# Unresolved type T when creating an Array<T> with generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript1.4

So I'm trying to create an object which has an arreay of projects I want projects to be a generic of but I'm getting error `unresolved type T`:

```
export class AllocationInvestorVO {
    public name: string;
    public id: string;
    public projects: Array<T>; //ERROR: unresolved type T
}
```

What I am aiming for is the polymorphism behavior we see in Java, that we can create a List object which can be extended to ArrayList for example:

How to Create an `Array` that Base type is for example `Project` and it can be polymorphed into Array of type `ProjectX` or `ProjectY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `projects` to be generic then you need to first declare the `AllocationInvestorVO` class as generic:

```
export class AllocationInvestorVO<T> {
    public name: string;
    public id: string;
    public projects: Array<T>; // ok
}
```

Otherwise `T` can't be resolved.
If you want to have a base for this `T` then:

```
export class AllocationInvestorVO<T extends Project> {
    public name: string;
    public id: string;
    public projects: Array<T>;
}
```